# Is there a way to return extended object without knowting it?

Tags: dart, extends

Let's assume that we have code as below. I would like to copy User object without knowing that he may be agent, and after copy I would like to receive Agent object if he was that object.

My goal would like to be some parsing function inside User so I don't have to check for object in later use cases.

Is there any way to return Agent object without knowing about it? Or I have to check if its Agent and then use something like this `(user as Agent).copyWith()`. It would be nice if I could avoid that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
class User {
        final String name;
    
        User(this.name);
    }
    
    
    class Agent extends User {
        Agent(super.name);
    }
    
    
    main() {
        final agent = Agent('name');
        runFunction(agent);
    }
    
    void runFunction(User user) {
    
        if(user is Agent) // true
    
        final copiedUser = user.copyWith(name: newName);
    
        if(copiedUser is Agent) // false
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `copyWith` method in `Agent` to return an object of that type. If the `user` object in question is an `Agent`, then a new `Agent` will be created.

```dart
class User {
  final String name;

  User(this.name);
  
  User copyWith({String? name}) => User(name ?? this.name);
}

class Agent extends User {
  Agent(super.name);
  
  @override
  Agent copyWith({String? name}) => Agent(name ?? this.name);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I do that, but unfortunately copyWith as you may see in runFunction is triggered on User object and that returns after copyWith an User object not Agent. I would like to achieve that copiedUser is Agent but hes not.

Comment: Oh I just tried on dartPad and it works. Hmm

Comment: Ok I know whats going on. I can't use freezed because i wan't to extends objects so I used https://pub.dev/packages/copy_with_extension_gen to generate CopyWith but unfortunately that doesnt support inheritance so I'll have to write own copyWith. Thanks in advance

Comment: While the type of the object is only confirmed to be `User` when you call the `copyWith` function, it is still an `Agent` internally, and so the `Agent` `copyWith` function is called nonetheless. This is true for all subclass method invocations: the known type at the point of invocation does not affect which method implementation is called.

Comment: Have you looked at Freezed's union features? They may suit your use case.

Comment: Yeah, I've just look at it and that was it. Thank you very much.